# Scala implicit conversion not getting applied on Java argument pattern

Tags: java, scala

I have given the static method

```
static void foo(Object... params)
```

in the Java class Bar and plan to call it as follows:

```
Bar.foo('x')
```

Which won't work beacause the method expects a Java character and somehow, the existing implicit conversion is not applied.

```
Bar.foo('x' : Character)
Bar.foo(new Character('x'))
```

will both do the trick, but hurt readability. Putting those constructs in an implicit conversion

```
implicit def baz(c : Char) = c : Character
```

does not work and I don't understand why. So my questions:
What is the problem here?
Is there a fix?

Comment: With Scala 2.11.1 I'm seeing the following error message:

    mario@tumbolia /tmp/test 1024 % scalac *
    Foo.scala:2: error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
      Bar.foo('x')
          ^
one error found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is very specific about why it will not use any of these implicits:

```
error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
```

`Object` is a synonym for `AnyRef`, and becaue that is the value it needs to call `foo` it refuses to apply any implicit conversions.

However, you can define a wrapper around `Bar.foo` to enable you to use literal characters:

```
def barFoo(chars: Character*) = Bar.foo(chars.toArray: _*)
barFoo('x')
```

Comment: The reasons for this are stated in https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6899 and the linked Google Groups conversation (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scala-internals/cwEyQCmjX24)

Answer (score 1):

The only variables that can be cast to an Object type are those which are class instance.
That exclude basic type like int, boolean, double.
These one need to be transform, respectively to the type : Integer, Boolean, Double.